# React - Cant access property of an object when it is clearly there

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Still hoping someone help me with guidance.

I am newbie learning by doing, not able to access an array property inside an object when it is clearly there as shown from same console log output.

The array property of the object is:

```
console.log("vCompanyStakeholders",vCompanyStakeholders, "vCompanyStakeholders['buyer']",vCompanyStakeholders['buyer'],"vCompanyStakeholders.buyer",vCompanyStakeholders.buyer );
```

Console output (as shown in image too):

vCompanyStakeholders {}buyer: (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]**proto**: Object vCompanyStakeholders['buyer'] undefined vCompanyStakeholders.buyer undefined

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Gi1.png)

Background:

1. I am initialising following in state : "companyStakeholders" : {},
2. Then in a separate function I am getting data using an API and inserting a few arrays in the above field. buyer (in the above question) is one of the arrays populated.
3. Then just before the above statement, in my question, I am saving the companyStakeholders in the variable vCompanyStakeholders as follows "const vCompanyStakeholders = this.state.companyStakeholders;"
   3> My intention is to use the buyer array by sending it as parameter to another function after the above statement but the array is coming as undefined. Hence using console.log for debugging.

As we can clearly see from the console.log that the buyer array exist. I am confused why I cant extract it into its own variable for further use. I understand being a newbie I am making some very silly mistake

Comment: We need to see the actual code, please.

Comment: Seems like `vCompanyStakeholders` is not an object, since it wouldn't print `{}buyer: [4]...` Maybe it is a string?

Comment: Sorry, I am initialising following in state  : "companyStakeholders" : {},  Then in a separate function I am getting data using API and inserting a few arrays in the above field. buyer in the above code is an array. Then just before the above statement I am saving the companyStakeholders in the variable vCompanyStakeholders as follows "const vCompanyStakeholders = this.state.companyStakeholders;" My intention is to use the buyer array by sending it as parameter to another function after this but the array is coming as undefined.  Hence using console.log for debugging.

Comment: As we can clearly see from the console.log that the buyer array exist. I am confused why I cant extract it into its own variable for further use. I understand being a newbie I am making some very silly mistake.

Comment: Sorry, I should have first thanked for your response

Comment: Btw, I hope you clicked on the link "console" to actually see how its presented in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Console.log(vCompanyStakeholders.buyer['PROPERTY IN BUYER YOU WANT TO LOG'])

Comment: buyer is an array. I might be using wrong terminology. My intention is extract  the array stored as buyer from the vCompanyStakeholders structure in its own variable, so that I can use it for further logic. buyer is not the only array I have to use but I am assuming once I resolve this others will follow same logic.

Comment: Sorry, I should have first thanked for your response